# IIS 6 suddenly requires authentication on a website

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6

Basically, all I did was redirect an old website in IIS management to a new local directory, and now all the pages suddenly require the HTTP authentication. I have checked the settings, and Enable Anonymous Access is checked, and lists a guest user. I then tried creating a new local user, making it guest-group member only, and entered that into the website IIS settings to use.

Still no luck. Why does IIS suddenly want authentication? What changed??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permissions on the directory to ensure that the user `Internet Guest Account` has read access.

Comment: Well that's odd, I clicked "Full control" for Network service for the folder, and I added the guest account to the folder security with "read" access, and it now works I think.

Answer (score 2):

Check account under which apppool is running. Does it have access on website folder?

Comment: Application pool identity is using Network Service. Network Service has access to the folder where the ASP source code is located. Edit: Well that's odd, I clicked "Full control" for Network service for the folder, and I added the guest account to the folder security with "read" access, and it now works I think.